# Add file to Startup list

Tags: vbscript, startup

I have an vbs application and i want it to add itself at Startup automaticaly when is launched. how can i do this?

here is the code:

```
Do 
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    objIE.Visible = 1 
    objIE.Navigate "xxxxxxx"
objIE.ToolBar        = False
    objIE.Resizable      = False
    objIE.StatusBar      = False 
objIE.FullScreen = True
objIE.Width = 275
objIE.Height = 230

    Do Until VarType(objIE) = 9 
        WScript.Sleep 1000 
    Loop 

    Set objIE = Nothing 
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the script to add itself to the user's startup folder each time it's launched? All you have to do for that is [create a shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to your script in that folder. I wouldn't recommend doing this, though. I don't know about anyone else, but I for one would be quite annoyed if some script tried to force its way into my autostart every time I launch it.

Comment: what i want is when i launch it to add himself to startup folder